# Haxe/OpenFL app targeting flash/html5/air(desktop). How to handle filesystem data writing/reading?

Tags: haxe, openfl

I'm making an app that needs to target flash/air and ideally html5. This app has a feature of writing data in filesystem.
I've started using Haxe/OpenFL (this is my first experience).

I understand that flash and html5 won't be able to access local user's filesystem to write and read data. So those version would have this feature swapped by storing data in the cloud.

But AIR always had a possibility to operate the filesystem.
So I have two quetions now:

1. Is it possible to package Haxe/OpenFL project into AIR app, and
   make a proper .air installer? Or should I be using some sorts of
   cpp/c++ alternatives? What's the best practice in such a case?
2. Which API of OpenFL/Haxe gives me the possibility to
       write data on filesystem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different platforms have different implementations to save/load user data. You should `#if` all the possible options for all the target platforms.
E.g.:

```
#if cpp
import haxe.io.Eof;
import sys.FileSystem;
import sys.io.File;
import sys.io.FileOutput;
import sys.io.FileInput;
 #else if flash
import flash.net.SharedObject;
import flash.net.SharedObjectFlushStatus;
import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
 #end
class FileIO {
   public function SaveData() : Void {
 #if cpp
     var Fout : FileOutput = null;
        try {
            myFout = sys.io.File.write("c:\mypath\myfile.name", false);
            myFout.writeInt32(100);
            [.....]
 #else if flash
     var shObj : SharedObject = null;
     try {
           shObj  = SharedObject.getLocal("mySHODATA");
           var ret : String = shObj.flush(MinFileSize);
           [......]
 #end
  }
}
```

and so on. flash AIR, long story short is just -pretty much- a flash wrapper for desktop execution. Imagine it as a swf container for desktop (instead of instantiating an swf container in a web browser). So AIR-wrapped app == flash/swf app. If you want to use AIR implementations for file access, you can do that by following [these steps](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7dc8.html).
If you use haxe, it has it's own implementation for different targets, i.e. "#if" will find "flash" branch true, even if you plan to AIR-wrap you flash-app; so you'll have to use sharedobject.
I think it's wiser to compile cpp against desktop target, instead of "flash + wrap around with AIR" later.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will consider everything you said.

Answer (score 1):

1. It's supposedly doable, haven't tried it though.
2. Check out `sys.FileSystem` and `sys.io`.

Answer (score 1):

this guide should walk you through the process of publishing for iOS and Android with AIR http://www.openfl.org/archive/community/installing-openfl/building-air/